# Can I travel to Dublin with a Permanent Residence Card ( issued from ITALY)?

Tags: visas, italy, dublin, lebanon

I am a Lebanese citizin, living in italy for the past 6 years. I hold Lebanese passport and Italian permanent residence card.

Can i go to Dublin for few days without a visa?

Comment: You can check entry requirements here http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, but the link does not have the option "holder of an EU permanent residence card" !
that's the tricky part!

Comment: What type of residence card do you have? See http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-eu-family-residence-card

Comment: i have a permanent residence card

Comment: Residence card of a family member of an EU citizen?

Comment: No! 
it's a permanent residence card!
after being a legal resident for 5 years, in possession of a work contract, and a certain income, i was eligible to apply for the "permanent residence card" instead of renewing the residence permit annually...

That's what i have!

Comment: In that case, you need a visa, as indicated by the Irish Government website. See also https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm

Comment: You can travel in the Schengen area with your permanent residence card, but Ireland is not in the Schengen area.

Answer (score 3):

The Irish Government has a website that tells you if you need a visa. It only asks about your nationality, not about permanent residence. From this, it appears that only your nationality matters and, as a Lebanese national, you need a visa.

If you don't want to trust this argument of "They'd ask about your permanent residence if it made a difference", you can look for more information on the [website of the Irish embassy in Italy](https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/italy/) or telephone them at +39 06 585 2381.